# Can you calculate a sample size from only the population number? Standard deviation not known.

Tags: statistics

Total population is 96. SD not known. Just from this information, can any formula be used to determine the sample size? The question also asks whether a sample of 15 is enough?
There are 96 machines and the sample size for these machines needs to be calculated without knowing the standard deviation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sample size for what measurements/tests?

Comment: Trying to work out how many machines should be in the sample to be a good representation of the population.

Comment: What does that mean, though? Good for what purpose? And how good?

Comment: SD of what? Sample size to estimate what statistical parameter?

Comment: So the question that has been given to me is "There are 96 models of a machine available in the market and these models need to be tested for energy consumption. What is the sample size that you should select? Would 15 randomly selected models be enough?"

Comment: Energy consumption is being tested.